# how to limit record in left join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT commerce_product_field_data_commerce_product__field_data_field_products.entity_id, field_products_commerce_product.nid FROM commerce_order o 
            join  commerce_payment_transaction t on o.order_id = t.order_id 
            join commerce_line_item i on o.order_id = i.order_id
            LEFT JOIN field_data_commerce_total s ON i.line_item_id = s.entity_id AND (s.entity_type = 'commerce_line_item' AND s.deleted = '0')
                LEFT JOIN field_data_commerce_product field_data_commerce_product ON i.line_item_id = field_data_commerce_product.entity_id AND (field_data_commerce_product.entity_type = 'commerce_line_item' AND field_data_commerce_product.deleted = '0')
        INNER JOIN commerce_product commerce_product_field_data_commerce_product ON field_data_commerce_product.commerce_product_product_id = commerce_product_field_data_commerce_product.product_id
        LEFT JOIN 


    (select * from field_data_field_products) 



    commerce_product_field_data_commerce_product__field_data_field_products ON commerce_product_field_data_commerce_product.product_id = commerce_product_field_data_commerce_product__field_data_field_products.field_products_product_id




    LEFT JOIN ( select nid as nid from node order by nid)



    field_products_commerce_product




    ON commerce_product_field_data_commerce_product__field_data_field_products.entity_id = field_products_commerce_product.nid LEFT JOIN (
    select r.entity_id, r.field_ranges_value from field_data_field_ranges r
    ) r

             on r.entity_id = field_products_commerce_product.nid
            WHERE t.status = 'success' and i.type = 'product' and o.Uid <> 0
         AND o.status IN  ('completed') and o.created >= '1483228800'  and o.created <= '1483315200'  and r.field_ranges_value = 'Tasty Sticks'
```

Is my sql

It is giving me 5 results. I only need 4

One of the product id's belong to two Drupal nodes and I only want one of them

I tried changing LEFT JOIN ( select nid as nid from node order by nid) to

LEFT JOIN ( select nid as nid from node order by nid limit 1) but then I don't get any records at all. Any idea what needs changing please other than removing one of the duplicate nodes. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the current result and the desired result. Without that, it's very hard to find a solution

Comment: It is ok thanks. I managed to get it working in the end. The problem wasn't what I thought it was. The same product with the same range was on two different nodes. Goodness knows why as it is a shopping site.  I was thinking the problem was that the same product could be in more than one range but limiting the range didn't have any affect on the result